# Use ".attr()" in jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, attr

```
$(".resource_body_build_stone_ok").click(function(){
    $.post("ajax.php",
    {
      build:"resource",
      id: $(this).attr('data-id-build'), 
      level:$(this).attr('data-level-build')
    },
    function(data,status){
        $(".resource_body").load("resource_b.php/?r=1");
        $(".frame_stock").load("stock.php");
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
```

If the value `id: $(this).attr('data-id-build')` is 1 to 10 , how can I set id value in `resource_b.php/?r=1` instead the value 1.

For example, if value of `$(this).attr('data-id-build')`=5 ==> `resource_b.php/?r=5`

Comment: You need to send the `id` back to your function and get it out of your `data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$(".resource_body_build_stone_ok").click(function(){
    var dID = $(this).attr('data-id-build'); //use this dID where you want use dynamic id
    $.post("ajax.php",
    {
      build:"resource",
      id: dID, 
      level:$(this).attr('data-level-build')
    },
    function(data,status){
        $(".resource_body").load("resource_b.php/?r=" + dID);
        $(".frame_stock").load("stock.php");
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".resource_body_build_stone_ok").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id-build');
    $.post("ajax.php",
    {
      build:"resource",
      id: $(this).attr('data-id-build'), 
      level:$(this).attr('data-level-build')
    },
    function(data,status){
        $(".resource_body").load("resource_b.php/?r=" + id);
        $(".frame_stock").load("stock.php");
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the example http://jsfiddle.net/2dJAN/85/

```
var id_build = $(this).attr('data-id-build')

 $(".resource_body").load("resource_b.php/?r="+id_build);
```

For reference I alert the url format in example.